# Anygantt - Is it possible to have two bars with multiple markers in one row?

Tags: gantt-chart, anychart

I am trying to create a chart that will look similar to this:

I want one milestone (Ponte Vecchio Base Die) to have **two bars** that have **multiple markers** on them.
[image: Example]

I found the AnyGantt Feature [Multiple Milestones](https://www.anychart.com/products/anygantt/gallery/Gantt_General_Features/Multiple_Milestones.php) and I also found this other AnyGantt example [Optimistic and Pessimistic Views on a Single Gantt](https://www.anychart.com/products/anygantt/gallery/Gantt_General_Features/Custom_Drawing.php). Is it possible to use both at the same time?

**Multiple Milestones:**

[image: Multiple Milestones]

**Optimistic and Pessimistic Views on a Single Gantt**
[image: Optimistic and Pessimistic Views on a Single Gantt]

***Has anyone achieved this in Anychart? Any advise/help is much appreciated. TIA.***

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of the AnyGantt 8.9.0 doesn't support this possibility. Markers can't be applied to different bars, they can be applied to the whole row only.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am considering trying a workaround where I'll have the milestones nested in its own parent level - then I would have the multiple milestones on the parent level and child level to try to achieve the same thing. Any thoughts on if that would work?

Comment: Do you milestones preview feature? - https://playground.anychart.com/api/core/gantt/elements/_samples/anychart.core.gantt.elements.MilestonesElement.preview

Comment: I am currently trying to implement the milestones preview feature using (https://playground.anychart.com/gallery/src/Gantt_General_Features/Milestones_Preview_Marker_Type)

I've tried using two different ways of enabling the preview, but both ways causes the chart not to load... any idea why? Is this part of a newer api release that I may not have?

These' are the way's I've tried: milestones.preview().enabled(true); AND var previews = timeLine.milestones().preview();
            previews.enabled(true);

Comment: Make sure that you are using v8.9.0 that support the milestones preview API

Comment: Thank you, I was able to change the version and get it to work!